# Set column of a select query from an array in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to set a column of a select query from an array? Assuming we have the following table and array:

### `items` table

| item |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| e |
| ... |
| z |

### array of ids

```
ARRAY[3, 5, 11]
```

How can we run a select query which gives the following result?

| item | id |
| --- | --- |
| a | 3 |
| b | 5 |
| c | 11 |

Comment: So what is the logic that maps `a` to `3` and `b` to `5`?

Comment: In this example, there is no specific logic for mapping other than inserting the array values to a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **could** do the following (based on assumptions! The `ORDER BY` is the key issue here):

- assumption (for this solution): there has to be a correspondance between your items and your array of ids, (in this case) the first (**when sorted alphabetically**) record of the `items` table has to correspond to the first element of the array table (**when taken element by element in INSERT order**).

  you could, if required, do various things such as, say, remove duplicates in the array or sort the array, but that wasn't asked.

So, our tables and data (all the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=78e3cfb191ce622c1df0b546ec76791f)):

```
CREATE TABLE items
(
  item TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

populate the table:

```
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d'), ('e'), ('f'), ('g');
```

And the array:

```
CREATE TABLE id_array
(
  the_arr INT[] 
);
```

The elements:

```
INSERT INTO id_array VALUES
(ARRAY[3,5,11]);
```

Now, we have to establish a `JOIN`ing criterion. As outlined above, this will be done by first, sorting the items table alphabetically. I've put a `PRIMARY KEY` on the `items` table but this isn't strictly necessary.

```
SELECT item, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item ASC)
FROM items
ORDER BY item ASC;
```

Result:

```
item    row_number
   a         1
   b         2
   c         3
   d         4
   e         5
   f         6
   g         7
```

and for the array (sorted by `INSERT` order):

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM UNNEST
     (
       (SELECT the_arr FROM id_array)
     ) WITH ORDINALITY AS t (elem, nr);
```

Result:

```
elem    nr
   3    1
   5    2
  11    3
```

So, now we join the two tables:

```
SELECT 
  tab1.item, tab1.rn,
  tab2.elem, tab2.nr
FROM
(
  SELECT i.item, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY item ASC) AS rn
  FROM items i
  ORDER BY i.item ASC
) AS tab1
JOIN
(
  SELECT
    * 
  FROM UNNEST
       (
         (SELECT the_arr FROM id_array)
       ) WITH ORDINALITY AS t (elem, nr)
) AS tab2
ON tab1.rn  = tab2.nr;
```

Result:

```
item    rn  elem    nr
   a     1     3     1
   b     2     5     2
   c     3    11     3
```

I'll leave the clearing up of the SQL to you! I found these posts helpful:

- [UNNEST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7309672/470530)
- Inserting [ARRAY values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33343939/470530) (reminder)
- [Ordinality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767450/470530)

Edited: I put an explicit `ORDER BY` clause in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function - thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name for pointing out that there could potentially be problems if this was not done!

Comment: To be clear, the query presented does NOT order `items`, and thus by standard, a random set of rows is returned.  If you, say, load `items` in reverse with `insert into tab1 select chr(generate_series(26, 1, -1)+96)`, then you will NOT get the requested output. The OP did not define the ordering or relationship of the data, so _caveat emptor_.

Comment: @dwhitemv Maybe you'd be so kind as to point out where I wasn't **crystal clear** as to where `ORDER BY` was required? God knows, I used enough **bold text**!

Comment: You are not using an `order by` for the `row_number()`  function, so the generated `rn` value is essentially random

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - does/can a window function ever **not** sort using the sort in the main query (if not otherwise specified)? Is the sort order undefined? Is there anything in the documentation about potential problems arising from this? Thanks for the heads up - the reason I didn't include the `ORDER BY` in the window function was to reduce potential overhead?

Comment: In SQL, *never* assume data is sorted. If you need data ordered, use ORDER BY. You can certainly optimize _when_ you sort, and PostgreSQL may help you in certain situations, but you must explicitly specify if you want ordering. Hash joins will brutally remind you of the lack of guarantee if you forget. Looks like you updated the query so my first comment is out of date.

Comment: Ahh, using ROW_NUMBER on both ends to dictate a join is clever.

Comment: Re: Ordering - The ordering is not specified and is not needed as part of the example in the question. The resulting query can be out order (e.g. the alphabetical order is not necessary).